# JavaScript -- clear form after values are submitted

Tags: javascript, spring

I am using the following JavaScript code to clear a form on my page.

```
document.getElementById("bulletinForm").reset();
```

This code does indeed clear my form, but it does it before the information is sent to the server.  I've tried calling as the onSubmit event on the form and as the onClick event on the Submit button.  How do I send the information to the server before clearing the form?  I am not currently using any Ajax with this.  All I have is a Spring form that looks like this.

```
<form:form commandName="bulletin" method="post" action="processBulletin">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name: <font style="font-weight: bold; color: red;">
            <c:out value='${nameRequired}' /></font><br /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:input path="name" id="name" maxlength="100" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Subject: <font style="font-weight: bold; color: red;">
            <c:out value='${subjectRequired}' /></font><br /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:input path="subject" id="subject" maxlength="1000" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">Message: <font style="font-weight: bold; color: red;">
            <c:out value='${messageRequired}' /></font><br /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>                            
            <td><form:textarea path="note" id="note" cols="80" rows="100" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit bulletin" onClick="clearForm()"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

Comment: Is your form being submitted asynchronously? Reset the form after the response from your AJAX request.

Comment: `.reset()` will clear the form in some Browsers and not others. You can run through the `formElement.elements` collection assigning `''` to the `.value` to clear each one off. Keep in mind this will clear your button values as well, so you'll need to think about that. Also, use AJAX.

Comment: @PHPglue But that will still happen before the submission, so it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Why do you need to clear the form if you're not using AJAX to submit it? Normal form submission reloads the page.

Comment: show the rest of the code that is relevant to the submit/reset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you clear the form before submitting you won't get any data. That's also what should be expected.
However you can circumvent this by sending the form without refreshing the site with an asynchroneous request. After sending the form data you can reset the form.
A fast way would be doing it with the Javascript Framework jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "url.html",
  data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
  success: function() {
    // This function is called after
    // sending the request successfully
    $('#myForm').trigger("reset");
  }
});
```

Sending AJAX request with pure Javascript is a bit more complicated.

Comment: You cold also reset the form in `beforeSend:`, so that it will be cleared while waiting for the response.

Comment: This form is a Spring form.  I am sending this to a method in a Spring controller.  How would the URL look in that case?  Would it end with .html as above?  How would I rewrite the Spring form tag?

Comment: It should work like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972823/spring-mvc-jquery-ajax-issue). Take notice of the `RequestMapping` annotation in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You could try manually submitting your form in Javascript, change the input type from submit to button and then you could have something like:

```
function onSubmit() {
  document.getElementById("bulletinForm").submit();
  document.getElementById("bulletinForm").reset();
  return false; //stop page refresh
}
```

Source: [Clearing my form inputs after submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589193/clearing-my-form-inputs-after-submission)

Comment: Code smell, don't repeat yourself. Use a local variable. KTHX

Comment: You could use a local var yes and I would use one if I were referencing that form more than twice, however personally I would not initialise a new var just for the above case.